# AWS - Multiple Service - Shared Load Balancer - Best Practice

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I'm migrating infrastructure from linode (bleh) to AWS (yay), and ran into an interesting scenario. I have 2 nodes which are behind an internal balancer and these 2 nodes will be running multiple services (ntp, puppetmaster, rsyslog aggregation, etc).

What is the best practice for monitoring multiple ports? Do I have to spin up a load balancer for each port I would like to monitor? Right now I have the load balancer set to monitor port 22 on each node, but obviously could result in a situation where puppetmaster may have stopped, but load balancer is still allowing requests because port 22 is still responding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet here is writing something like an xinetd service that checks health of the various components and reports back a single OK/not-OK response. ELB supports only one check per ELB.

You could also point multiple ELBs at the set of servers. It'll cost you about $15/month per additional ELB. As a bonus, it'll make things easier if you want to split a service off to a separate set of servers down the line.